# Detect which frameworks are added to project?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to programmatically figure out if a certain framework (say, CoreLocation) is added to the project?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSClassFromString` is your friend. Look for a class in those libraries. If you get back `Nil`, then you don't have it linked. Otherwise, it is.